# activerecord has_one

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a model `Show` and a model `Artist`. I want a reference from `Show` to `Artist`, but not vice versa.

So a `Show` has an `Artist` and that's it. I did this:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :artist
end
```

but it doesn't work. Everytime I do:

```
a_show.artist = an_artist
```

it doesn't assign it. Also I get this:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `show_id'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use`attr_writer` etc. (called from irb_binding at (irb):3)

In my db, I have a column called `artist_id` in `shows` table of type `Integer`.

Comment: Do you have tried put the belongs_to :show on Artist model, just for test purposes, to see if this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a column called artist_id in shows table of type Integer

In this case, the relation in the class `Show` should be `belongs_to` instead of `has_one` (the `belongs_to` is always on the class which contains the foreign key).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But don't you think the it should be called "has_one" as that makes more sense, no? A show has (has_one) an artist, not belongs_to. Anyways, that worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association)

[image]

but what you need is belongs_to, to be able to achieve what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For such type of confusion you should to refer [Choosing Between belongs_to and has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) section of Rails guide.

If you want to set up a one-to-one relationship between two models, you'll need to add belongs_to to one, and has_one to the other. How do you know which is which?

The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the table for the class declaring the belongs_to association), but you should give some thought to the actual meaning of the data as well. The has_one relationship says that **one of something is yours** - that is, that something points back to you. For example, it makes more sense to say that a supplier owns an account than that an account owns a supplier. This suggests that the correct relationships are like this:

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

The corresponding migration might look like this:

```
class CreateSuppliers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :suppliers do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.integer :supplier_id
      t.string  :account_number
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```